# $\mathbb{C}$-linearity and complex-linear matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, lie-algebras

i'm studying complex-matrics from Tapp's book( Matrix Groups for Undergraduates)...and i need help!

$\textbf{Prerequisites}$

$f_n:  \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, 
$f_n(a_1+b_1\textbf{i},a_2+b_2\textbf{i},...,a_n+b_n\textbf{i}):=(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...,a_n,b_n)$

$\rho_n:  M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$.
$\rho_n$ is defined in this way:

$\rho_1(a+b\textbf{i}) := \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\  -b & a \end{pmatrix} $

For $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $n>1$, we build $\rho_n(A)$ out of 2-by-2 blocks equal to $\rho_1$ applied to the entries of A. For example,

$\rho_2\begin{pmatrix} a+b\textbf{i} & c+d\textbf{i} \\  e+f\textbf{i} & h+j\textbf{i} \end{pmatrix} $ = $\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\  -b & a & -d & c\\ e & f & h & j \\ -f & e & -j & h \end{pmatrix} $.

$\rho_n$ so defined makes the following diagram commutative:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miVKn.jpg)

$\textbf{Definition}$: Matrices of $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ in the image $\rho_n$ are called complex-linear real matrices.

$\textbf{My problem}$ is about this proposition:(Prop. 2.4 Tapp's book)

$B \in  M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$  is complex-linear iff the function $F:=f_n^{-1} \circ R_B \circ f_n : \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{C}^{n} $ is a  $\mathbb{C}$-linear transformation.

In particular, i had some difficulties on this direction: if F is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, then B is a complex matrix.

I tried in this way:

I assume that B is a complex-linear matrix iff $\exists A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ : $\rho_n(A)=B$.
To build $A$ I consider $R_A$ (linear transformation $R_A:  \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{C}^{n}$ , $R_A(X)=XA, \forall X$) as the application $F$ ($R_A:=F$) and i write the matrix A associated to $R_A=F$, using natural basis. From my
calculus i find the thesis, $\rho_n(A)=B$.

It was told that my method is wrong for the arbitrariness of the basis. I have not other ideas.
Do you have other hints?
Thank you all.

Comment: What does the notation $R_A$ mean? What is $R$?

Comment: $R_A$ is  a linear transformation 
that to each vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ associates the vector-matrix product $vA$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ , so $R_B$ associates to each vector $u\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ the vector-matrix product $uB$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of a proof. Write $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ for the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $e_1, \ldots, e_{2n}$ for the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Suppose that $B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $F = f_n^{-1} \circ R_B \circ f_n$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Firstly, we have that

$$F(z_1) = f_n^{-1}(R_B(e_1)) = f_n^{-1}(\text{first row of $B$}) = (B_{11} + iB_{12}, B_{13} + iB_{14}, \ldots)$$

Next, we have that

$$F(iz_1) = f_n^{-1}(R_B(e_2)) = f_n^{-1}(\text{second row of $B$}) = (B_{21} + iB_{22}, B_{23} + iB_{24}, \ldots)$$

Now we apply the hypothesis that $F$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, which says that $F(iz_1) = iF(z_1)$. Comparing the first coordinates of these, we get

$$(B_{21} + iB_{22}) = i(B_{11} + iB_{12})$$

which gives that $B_{11} = B_{22}$, and $B_{21} = -B_{12}$. So at least the top left $2\times2$ submatrix of $B$ has the correct form, and it should be clear how to extend this argument to the whole of $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much. More or less i gave a proof like you, but yours is more elegant. Despite that it was reprimanded for using an arbitrary basis like standard basis...and i don't understand why. infact, i agree with you. Thanks again.

Comment: @David8 The standard basis is not arbitrary here, it's the basis in which the matrix $B$ represents the operator $R_B$. I wonder what your instructor had in mind.